Conceptually understanding microstates
I had learned about microstates in my thermodynamics class, but I am having trouble understanding the probabilistic property of them. My teacher had told me that every microstate is equally probable, but every configuration is not, which I understood. However, he said that the probability of a configuration (macrostate) occurring is determined by the number of microstates it has, or its multiplicity. I am confused by this, as the way I am perceiving it makes it seem as there is an extremely small but possible chance that particles could be highly disuniform for a particular instance. For example, take the diagram shown below:

This diagram shows 2 containers that contain a total of 10 particles. We can assume that the spacing between the containers is able to be traversed across by the particles freely. Using the equation for microstates,

where N_up is the number of particles in the first container and N_down is the number of particles in the second container, I get 252 microstates for the 5 particle-5 particle macrostate as shown in the image. However, let us say that the configuration changed into a 10 particle-0 particle distribution, delineating only a single microstate. Shouldn't this mean that this microstate is only 252 times less likely of occuring than the even distribution? By that logic, could there be an instance where one of the containers physically has no particles in it? To extend my question further, doesn't that mean there could be an instance, although extremely unlikely, where you could be in a room and all of the particles would disappear? I'm sure such an instance would be undetectable, but couldn't this still happen, or is there a hole in my understanding of how microstates function?

I think you gotta specify more clearly what these N's and N_up's represent.

Okay @StevenSagona I made that edit.

What if $N=10^{25}$?

Yeah I thought about that, but there still would be some probability of the 10^25-0 macrostate occuring, even though it is highly unlikely.

@alex Yes, that is correct. Thermodynamics does not rule out the possibility of unlikely microstates occurring (if a microstate was totally impossible it would not be in our set of microstates in the first place) but it does allow us to calculate just how extremely unlikely they are when large numbers of particles are involved.

You can use a similar formula to figure out what is the probability of this effect occurring in a room with $10^{25}$ molecules (you can use Stirling's approximation to estimate the factorials). You will find that the relative probability is way smaller than $1/252$.
